# GraphAPI error in Facebook python SDK: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook SDK for python to programmatically post photos to a fan page I manage. Everything works perfectly locally, but fails in production with the error: `GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Tinkering around shows me that the access_token and facebook_page_id are coming up as `None` in the code. That's weird because I've set them as environment variables on my server - writing `env` in the terminal shows them correctly set. I originally added them to `.profile` and then used the `source` command. I'm trying to import them in the code via `os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID')` and `os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN')`. What else can I do? It works perfectly fine if I hardcode the values in my code.

---

Here's my full code:

```
import facebook, os

def photo_poster(image_obj=None, caption=None):

  PAGE_ID = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID')
  ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN')

  cfg = {
    "page_id"      : PAGE_ID,  # Step 1
    "access_token" : ACCESS_TOKEN   # Step 3
    }
  api = get_api(cfg)
  status = api.put_photo(image=(image_obj),message=caption)

def get_api(cfg):
  graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cfg['access_token'])
  resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')
  page_access_token = None
  for page in resp['data']:
    if page['id'] == cfg['page_id']:
      page_access_token = page['access_token']
  graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
  return graph
```

In .profile I've included the following lines:

```
export FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID=12345678
export FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN=ADAFASFGASGfsadfsadf4
```

(dummy values are shown)